# Traffic modelling on ns-3 network Simulator

Tags: ns-3

I am trying to simulate traffic of voice, video, and data in order to check the differences between EDCF and traditional CSMA/CA.

I am using an on off helper based on the example of http://www.scielo.org.co/pdf/dyna/v84n202/0012-7353-dyna-84-202-00055.pdf

for the video but on setAttribute(“OffTime”, StringValue(“ns3::LogNormalRandomVariable[Mu=0.4026,Sigma=0.0352]”));

I get error 'Attribute value "0.4026,Sigma=0.0352" is not properly formatted'

Any ideas for the error or suggestions on  how to model the three types of traffic?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find the version of ns3 in your provided reference. Also, the reference paper was published in September 2017. I think, they have used ns3.26 probably. 
So, I've tried with ns3.29 and couldn't reproduce the above error. I've got somewhat different error. But I could fixed it by putting a space before '['.
The second solution I found by using `Mu` and `Sigma` separately.

```
onoff.SetAttribute ("OffTime", StringValue("ns3::LogNormalRandomVariable[Mu=0.4026]"));
onoff.SetAttribute ("OffTime", StringValue("ns3::LogNormalRandomVariable[Sigma=0.0352]"));
```

[image: For more details see the attached picture]

Comment: This answer is not correct. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

a4arshad's answer's compile and run, but they are not correct. The reason a4arshad's solution does not work is that the second `SetAttribute` call sets the `OffTime` attribute as a `LogNormalRandomVariable` with `Sigma=0.0352`. The second call does not *add* to the existing `LogNormalRandomVariable` with `Mu=0.4026`. The second call *overwrites* the first one.

a4arshad also suggested putting a space between `LogNormalRandomVariable` and `[`, but that doesn't work either; this will just cause ns-3 to ignore all parameters.

The correct way to set the attribute as the linked paper is to delimit parameters using a pipe, `|`. You should do something like

```cpp
onoff.SetAttribute("OffTime", StringValue("ns3::LogNormalRandomVariable[Mu=0.4026|Sigma=0.0352]"));
```

I don't know when ns-3 switched to using a pipe to instead of a comma, but I am using the most recent release version, ns-3.30.1.

You can use the following program to check whether setting an attribute worked. The last lines are the relevant ones; the rest is boilerplate to set up the simulation. In the last lines, we extract the `Attribute` from the `Application`, and print the Mu and Sigma values. Try commenting/uncommenting the correct/incorrect methods and look at the different outputs. According to the documentation of [`LogNormalRandomVariable`](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/classns3_1_1_log_normal_random_variable.html), the default values of Mu and Sigma are 0 and 1, respectively.

```cpp
/* -*- Mode:C++; c-file-style:"gnu"; indent-tabs-mode:nil; -*- */

// setting a LogNormalRandomVariable with multiple parameters as the OffTime
// of an OnOffApplication
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60791009
// Author: Sagar

#include "ns3/core-module.h"
#include "ns3/internet-module.h"
#include "ns3/point-to-point-module.h"
#include "ns3/ipv4-global-routing-helper.h"
#include "ns3/applications-module.h"

using namespace ns3;

NS_LOG_COMPONENT_DEFINE("RandomVariableAttirbuteTest");

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NodeContainer nodes;
    nodes.Create(2);

    PointToPointHelper p2pLink;
    NetDeviceContainer devices = p2pLink.Install(nodes);

    InternetStackHelper stack;
    stack.InstallAll();

    // assign IP addresses to NetDevices
    Ipv4AddressHelper address ("10.1.1.0", "255.255.255.0");
    Ipv4InterfaceContainer ipInterfaces = address.Assign(devices);
    Ipv4GlobalRoutingHelper::PopulateRoutingTables();

    // configure and install server app
    int serverPort = 8080;
    UdpServerHelper serverApp (serverPort);
    serverApp.Install(nodes.Get(0));
    Address serverAddress = InetSocketAddress(ipInterfaces.GetAddress(0), serverPort);

    // configure and install client apps
    OnOffHelper onoff ("ns3::UdpSocketFactory", serverAddress);

    // incorrect (two separate SetAttribute calls)
    // onoff.SetAttribute("OffTime", StringValue("ns3::LogNormalRandomVariable[Mu=0.4026]"));
    // onoff.SetAttribute("OffTime", StringValue("ns3::LogNormalRandomVariable[Sigma=0.0352]"));

    // also incorrect (adding a space)
    // onoff.SetAttribute("OffTime", StringValue("ns3::LogNormalRandomVariable [Mu=0.4026,Sigma=0.0352]"));

    // correct
    onoff.SetAttribute("OffTime", StringValue("ns3::LogNormalRandomVariable[Mu=0.4026|Sigma=0.0352]"));

    onoff.Install(nodes.Get(1));

    // print Attirbutes to check if they were correctly set
    Ptr<Application> app = nodes.Get(1)->GetApplication(0);
    PointerValue pv;
    app->GetAttribute("OffTime", pv);
    Ptr<LogNormalRandomVariable> rv = pv.Get<LogNormalRandomVariable>();
    NS_LOG_UNCOND("Mu = " << rv->GetMu());
    NS_LOG_UNCOND("Sigma = " << rv->GetSigma());

    return 0;
}
```